# Java выполнение повторяющихся заданий

Tags: java, многопоточность, таймер

Есть сервис, который надо запускать периодически. Как лучше реализовать периодическое выполнение задания на джаве? Какие "за" и "против" использования Thread.sleep, TimerTask и тредпула?

```
package main;

import services.Service;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Service s = new Service();
        while (true) {
            s.service();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: расшифруйте "сервис" и его контескт - это JavaEE, Android, Play!Framework или что то еще? в данном случае ответ сильно зависит от контекста и универсального рецепта нет. Даже Thread.sleep несмотря на все его недостатки может оказаться наиболее приемлемым в некоторых случаях.

Comment: @Ramiz, это JavaEE, сервис, работающий с MongoDB и Postgres

Comment: А есть смысл такой сервис постоянно держать в памяти? Может каким-то cron-ом вызывать нужную джарку?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Answer (score 2):

При разработке прикладного программного обеспечения надо всегда стремиться использовать абстракции как можно более высокого уровня, в особенности если это enterprise-приложение. Не знаю, что конкретно вы имеете ввиду под "сервисом JavaEE", но EJB-контейнер предоставляет инфраструктуру как для управления потоками, так и для периодических задач. Используйте [@Schedule](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Schedule.html) и [@Timeout](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Timeout.html) вместо `Thread.sleep()`, `TimerTask` и тому подобного.

```
@Singleton
public class TimerBean {
    @Schedule(second = "*/5", minute = "*", hour = "*", persistent = false)
    public void periodicTask() throws InterruptedException {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, @Shedule отличное решение, только вместо всех этих параметров можно использовать сразу cron @Scheduled(cron = "*/5 * * * * *").